# Colon in arguments of a method call - Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

when looking to some Ruby code I found the following method:

```
def connection
    unless @_mc_connection && valid? && @_ns_version == get_version
      @_mc_connection = ::Dalli::Client.new(self.dalli_servers, self.dalli_options.merge(namespace: namespace))
    end
    @_mc_connection
  end
```

My question is about the use of `dalli_options.merge(namespace: namespace)`. What is the purpose of the colon here? Is an hash member?

Comment: Google "ruby hash syntax"

Comment: Yes,it's a hash. When hash key is a symbol,you can write it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the colon here? Is an hash member?

Yes, it is a Hash object.

A [**`Hash`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html) can be easily created by using its implicit form:

```
grades = { "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 6 }
```

Hashes allow an alternate syntax form when your keys are always symbols. Instead of

```
options = { :font_size => 10, :font_family => "Arial" }
```

You could write it as:

```
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
```

Comment: I had to try that, as I would have thought `{}` would be required to distinguish a hash from a named parameter.  Sure enough, `{}.merge(hat: 'cat') => {:hat=>"cat"}`.  Aha, a named parameter is nothing more than a hash!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the Ruby version, this is either a `Hash` literal (1.9) or a keyword argument (2.0+).

Answer (score 1):

The colon is part of the symbol syntax.

The following are equivalent:

```
namespace:   #only valid inside a hash
```

and

```
:namespace
```

With the former, the 'hash rocket' operator (`=>`) can be omitted (and usually is, for ease of reading).

However, this is only the case when your keys are symbols. If your keys are strings, as in

```
{ 'namespace' => 'api' }
```

the hash rocket is required.